# React Native, not understanding async function flow with call to firebase

Tags: react-native

My goal is, for useEffect to hit my firebase database and load information from it to display. But it is returning too early. I have 2 console.logs. The "z" log is returning before the "y". And thus, tempArray is empty. The "y" console has tempArray populated. It just prints to the screen BEFORE the empty "z". And thus, nothing displays. How can I fix this? What did I code wrong? I hope I explained it well, if not I will edit with more code. Thanks for any help.

```
  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      processList();
    }, [])
  );

  const processList = async () => { 
    let tempArray = [];
    query.once("value")
    .then(function(snapshot) {
      snapshot.forEach((child)=>{     
          if (child.key == id){
            let matchingDeals = child.val().matchingDeals;
            let mdArray = matchingDeals.split(',');
            mdArray.forEach((element)=> {
              db.ref('deals/' + element).once("value")
              .then((dealSnapshot)=>{
                    tempArray.push({
                      id: dealSnapshot.key,
                      title: dealSnapshot.val().hasOwnProperty('title') ? dealSnapshot.val().title : 'NA',
                      currentPrice: dealSnapshot.val().price,
                    })
                    console.log(tempArray + ' y '); 
              })
              .catch((error) => Sentry.Native.captureException('Error NotificationsCard function processList 1 ' + error))
            })
            console.log(tempArray + ' z ');
            setListNotifs(tempArray);
          }
      })
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      Sentry.Native.captureException('Error NotificationsCard function processList 2 ' + error)
    });
 }
```

Comment: you not using useEffect. In your code is useFocusEffect.
change it to 
React.useEffect(() =>{ 
 processList()
},[])

Comment: good catch, seems my problem is still there however I needed to change that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After reading some tutorials I found changing my code to return promises instead of trying to make one big then function, works for what I'm trying to do:

```
  useEffect( ()=> {
    processList();
  }, []) 

 const processList = async () => { 
    let tempArray = [];
    query.once("value")
    .then(function(snapshot) {
      let promises = [];
      snapshot.forEach((child)=>{     
        if (child.key == id){
          let matchingDeals = child.val().matchingDeals;
          let mdArray = matchingDeals.split(',');
          mdArray.forEach((element)=> {
            promises.push(
              db.ref('deals/' + element).once("value")
            );
          })
        }
      })
      return Promise.all(promises);
    }).then(function(snapshots) {
      snapshots.forEach((child)=>{     
          tempArray.push({
            id: child.key,
            title: child.val().hasOwnProperty('title') ? child.val().title : 'NA',
            currentPrice: child.val().price,
          })
      })
      return tempArray;
    }).then(function(tempArray) {
      setListNotifs(tempArray); 
    })
 }
```